# How to write a conditional that checks if a variable falls within a range of values?

Tags: javascript

I want to test whether a variable is equal to another variable, or within +5 or -5 that other variable. What's the most succinct way to write this?

```
if(foo === bar || foo === bar + 5 || foo === bar - 5) { // do stuff };
```

Not only is this long but it won't evaluate to true if foo = bar + 4, or bar + 3 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (Math.abs(foo - bar) <= 5)` tells you if `foo` and `bar` are within 5 of each other.

You see this frequently when comparing equality subject to linear tolerance.

Comment: Other guy was first but this might be more succinct for what I have to use this for. Will test :o

Comment: Interesting solution. Ran a JSPerf and this is [only marginally slower](http://jsperf.com/relational-vs-math-abs) than using relational operators.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [Relational Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators) (`>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=`):

```
if (foo <= bar + 5 && foo >= bar - 5)
```

Comment: *facepalm* 

Of course. But that's not right. You need && not the double pipes. Otherwise that conditional you've written will evaluate to virtually any value.

if(foo >= bar -5 && foo <= bar + 5) { // }

Comment: @Gaweyne oops. Changed that!